# Opencv 2.4.11 Windows 8 Visual studio 2012 professional The application was unable to start correctly (0xc00007b)

Tags: opencv

I just follow the tutorial on

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html#windows-visual-studio-how-to

and set the project property --> C/c++ directory to C:\opencv\build\include

and linker--> additonal library directory to C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib

linker --> input : 
opencv_calib3d2411d.lib opencv_contrib2411d.lib opencv_core2411d.lib opencv_features2d2411d.lib opencv_flann2411d.lib opencv_gpu2411d.lib opencv_highgui2411d.lib opencv_imgproc2411d.lib opencv_legacy2411d.lib opencv_ml2411d.lib opencv_nonfree2411d.lib opencv_objdetect2411d.lib opencv_ocl2411d.lib opencv_photo2411d.lib opencv_stitching2411d.lib opencv_superres2411d.lib opencv_ts2411d.lib opencv_video2411d.lib opencv_videostab2411d.lib

and use the test code here

http://docs.opencv.org/_downloads/introduction_windows_vs.cpp

it built successully but when i run it just say: The application was unable to start correctly (0xc00007b)

[image]

Comment: Both of the links you posted don't work. Please replace these dead links with working ones or pasted code.

Comment: Already done. repaste the link